# Nsetools API's not working when deployed on ec2 instance

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, aws-security-group, stockquotes

I am planning to use nsetools library with python to get top gainers and top losers.
the code is working fine on local and getting me all the information but when I deployed same code on ec2 instance the code **nse.get_top_gainers()** is getting timed out.

Comment: I am facing same issue. Any way to resolve this?

Comment: which region it is?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like NSE blocked the access from VM's and the cloud machines.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).